# How to add an array to an empty array in React using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a random name generator where a user would input a bunch of names in a text box, and then it would output a single name from the array.

So far I have the following:

```js
function App() {
  const [firstNames, setFirstNames] = useState(['']);
  
  const submitResults = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(firstNames.length);
  };
  
  return (
    <main>
      <form onSubmit={submitResults}>
        <div className="container">
          <NameField
            htmlFor="first-selection"
            id="first-selection"
            title="Selection 1"
            value={firstNames}
            onChange={(e) => setFirstNames(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
     </form>
    </main> 
   );
}
```

But when I console.log the `firstNames.length`, I'm getting the character number instead. For example, if I submit **[hello, there]**, I'll get 12 as the `firstNames.length` instead of 2. I tried playing around with the onChange, but I'm still not sure how to update the firstNames state so it adds the array properly.

Comment: Because `e.target.value` is a string. You have to convert that to a JSON array. Try using `JSON.parse(e.target.value)`

Comment: If I add JSON.parse and start typing the letter "h" (for example), I'll get an error that says "Unexpected token h at JSON)..."

Comment: Try this `onChange={(e) => setFirstNames([...firstNames,e.target.value])}` .

Comment: That's close, but if I type it'll continuously add whatever I typed before for example, if I type "hello" the array would be ["h", "he", "hel", "hell", "hello"]

Comment: Are you saying a user enters a comma separated list?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, the user would be entering the commas to separate the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've entered a string of comma separated names, so when you want to process this as an array you need to convert the string into an array of strings.

Use [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the `firstNames` state by "," to get an array.

```
firstNames.split(',').length
```

[image: Edit how-to-add-an-array-to-an-empty-array-in-react-using-hooks]

```
function App() {
  const [firstNames, setFirstNames] = useState("");

  const submitResults = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(firstNames.split(",").length);
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <form onSubmit={submitResults}>
        <div className="container">
          <input
            htmlFor="first-selection"
            id="first-selection"
            title="Selection 1"
            value={firstNames}
            onChange={(e) => setFirstNames(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit">Check Names</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: @imnewhere Don't forget to use any array filtering and string trimming functions in case the user enters something like "   name one  ,     nameTwo, ,     , three,,  " so you can junk the empty strings. Basically just sanitize the input before you consume it elsewhere.